# AutoMapper - Trying to flatten my object property to string but getting an error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, automapper

I am trying to map my `ProductDto` to `Product` class. I get an error when mapping the string property in `ProductDto` class to a `Brand` property in the `Product` class.

```
AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.

Mapping types:
ProductDto -> Product
SilksyAPI.Dto.ProductDto -> SilksyAPI.Entities.Product

Type Map configuration:
ProductDto -> Product
SilksyAPI.Dto.ProductDto -> SilksyAPI.Entities.Product

Destination Member:
Brand

 ---> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
String -> Brand
System.String -> SilksyAPI.Entities.Brand
```

Here is my mapping profile:

```cs
CreateMap<Product, ProductDto>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Brand, opt => opt.MapFrom(p => p.Brand.Name))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Categories, opt => opt.MapFrom(p => p.ProductCategories.Select(pc => pc.Category.Name)));

CreateMap<ProductDto, Product>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Brand, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name));
```

Classes:

```cs
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public int BrandId { get; set; }
    public Brand Brand { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ProductCategory> ProductCategories { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class Brand
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Dto Class

```cs
 public class ProductDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public List<string> Categories { get; set; }

}
```

I have tried different mapping profiles but I cannot map from `ProductDto` to `Product` but can map from `Product` to `ProductDto` with no problem.

Here are a few other things I tried

```cs
CreateMap<Brand, string>()
    .IncludeMembers(b => b.Name);


CreateMap<Product, ProductDto>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Brand, opt => opt.MapFrom(p => p.Brand.Name))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Categories, opt => opt.MapFrom(p => p.ProductCategories.Select(pc => pc.Category.Name)))
    .ReverseMap();
```

And

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<Brand, string>().ConvertUsing(source => source.Name ?? string.Empty);
```

https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Flattening.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your first mapping profile, when mapping from `ProductDto` to `Product`, for `Brand` property, you need to create a new `Brand` instance as below:

```cs
cfg.CreateMap<ProductDto, Product>()
   .ForMember(dest => dest.Brand, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => new Brand { Name = src.Name }));
```

[Sample Program](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nDNRdZ)

---

> For `.IncludeMembers()`

I don't think it suits your scenario as you are mapping from `object` to `string` but not `object` to `object`.

---

> For `.ConvertUsing()`

You need to add the code below to mapping from `string` to `Brand` for Brand property.

```cs
cfg.CreateMap<string, Brand>()
   .ConvertUsing(source => new Brand { Name = source });
```

[Sample program (`.ConvertUsing()`)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Hs2ttG)